# Unable to retrieve email folders on specific mail server.. possible causes

Tags: c#, .net, imapx

I am failing to retrieve the folders of my email account using ImapX:

```
 ImapX.ImapClient m_ImapClient = new ImapX.ImapClient( ImapServerAddress, (int) ImapServerPort, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3, false);
 m_ImapClient.Connect();
 m_ImapClient.Login( EmailAddress, EmailPassword);
//the two functions above each return true
//this last statement throws an exception:
ImapX.Collections.FolderCollection vFolders = m_ImapClient.Folders;
```

and that is:

```
'm_ImapClient.Folders' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' ImapX.Collections.CommonFolderCollection {System.NullReferenceException}
```

What's wrong, I'm using IMAP, ssl, port 993. ImapX 2. This works for imap.google.com on 993, but doesn't work for another network server.. Any ideas of why this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed, thank you! For details see [Issue: Unable to get mail folders after successfull login on IMAP server](https://imapx.codeplex.com/workitem/1779). The problem occured on parsing the information returned by the IMAPX server about folders. Some servers do not quote the folder names.